# Left and right margin changes

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

While converting from aspose words 15.6 or 16.8 I noticed that left and right margin changes, conversion is not really like the word document.
I am not setting any page setup or margin, my purpose is just to have the exact same document. 
Is there's a reason for that? How can I avoid it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please try the [latest version of Aspose.Words](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/net) i.e. 19.4 and see how it goes on your end. In case the problem still remains, please ZIP and upload your input document and Aspose.Words generated output document showing the undesired behavior here for testing or you may upload to Dropbox and share the download link here. We will then investigate the issue on our end and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't share the documents as it is confidential, but can you confirm me please that this is a known bug maybe as I can't also upgrade directly as we use it in big project, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to say what the problem is without checking your input/output documents. You can remove any sensitive information by replacing it with dummy data instead. Also, we have introduced many new features, enhancements and implemented many bug fixes during 15.6 to 19.4 transition. So, we strongly recommend you please upgrade to the latest version of Aspose.Words for .NET i.e. 19.4.